# Wait until option JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I wanted to know if JMeter has a option where you wait until some element disappears.

Example a loading bar only once that has completed or no longer visible then to carry on. (Also being able to monitor the length of time taken)

I have through about writing it as a webdriver test and then running it as a Junit test in JMeter but wanted to know if there is a simpler solution.

Any ideas welcome :)

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? thanks

Comment: I used a regex which looked for the element and a while loop which keeps going until its found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to realize that [JMeter is not a browser](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter doesn't execute any client-side JavaScript, the only way of implementing "wait until" option is using [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) in order to re-execute the same request again and again until response data will contain (or stop containing) the element you're looking for.

---

If you need to evaluate client-side JavaScript the only option would be going for Selenium. I would recommend using [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) instead of going for JUnit as this way you won't have to recompile your script for any change, it will be inlined into .jmx

Comment: Thanks, I used a regex which looked for the element and a while loop which keeps going until its found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transaction Controller to monitor the time taken by the whole process and to wait for a change , have a look at this:

- http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/waiting-for-a-page-change-in-jmeter