# JMeter waitfor page to load fully

Tags: jmeter

is it possible to wait for XPath or CSS selector to display in Jmeter?

I am using HTTP request to send API call and I have assertion as CSS selector path but due to API slowness , I would like to implement a waitfor method for the specific element in UI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until option JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712712/wait-until-option-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't execute any [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions) or [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) until it gets response from the server therefore you don't need to do anything. See [Execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) user manual chapter for more details.

---

However if I misunderstood your requirement and you want to repeat a HTTP request until XPath or CSS extractor return the value you're looking for you can put the request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and put the condition of your choice there:

[image]

In the above case:

- On iteration 0 of the While Controller `${myVariable}` doesn't have any value (CSS Selector Extractor hasn't been executed yet)
- Iterations from 1 to 5 - `${myVariable}` has value of `foo` which doesn't match While Controller's condition so it loops over
- Iteration 6 - `${myVariable}` value becomes `bar` and the While Controller exits the loop.

Just in case, textual representation of the [jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) used to compare variable with some value:

```
${__jexl3("${myVariable}" != "bar",)}
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitri would you be able to upload above sample so i can see what you have done ,please